# load csv into 2D matrix with numpy for plotting

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, reshape

Given this CSV file:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","F","timestamp"
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291111964948E12
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291113113366E12
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291120650486E12
```

I simply want to load it as a matrix/ndarray with 3 rows and 7 columns.  However, for some reason, all I can get out of numpy is an ndarray with 3 rows (one per line) and no columns.

```
r = np.genfromtxt(fname,delimiter=',',dtype=None, names=True)
print r
print r.shape

[ (611.88243, 9089.5601000000006, 5133.0, 864.07514000000003, 1715.3747599999999, 765.22776999999996, 1291111964948.0)
 (611.88243, 9089.5601000000006, 5133.0, 864.07514000000003, 1715.3747599999999, 765.22776999999996, 1291113113366.0)
 (611.88243, 9089.5601000000006, 5133.0, 864.07514000000003, 1715.3747599999999, 765.22776999999996, 1291120650486.0)]
(3,)
```

I can manually iterate and hack it into the shape I want, but this seems silly.  I just want to load it as a proper matrix so I can slice it across different dimensions and plot it, just like in matlab.

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Pure numpy

```
numpy.loadtxt(open("test.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",", skiprows=1)
```

Check out the [loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt) documentation.

You can also use python's csv module:

```
import csv
import numpy
reader = csv.reader(open("test.csv", "rb"), delimiter=",")
x = list(reader)
result = numpy.array(x).astype("float")
```

You will have to convert it to your favorite numeric type. I guess you can write the whole thing in one line:

```
result = numpy.array(list(csv.reader(open("test.csv", "rb"), delimiter=","))).astype("float")
```

**Added Hint:**

You could also use `pandas.io.parsers.read_csv` and get the associated `numpy` array which can be faster.

Comment: I would add that the skiprows=1 flag is skipping the first row, and is not a standard activation flag if you want to keep all the data. Worked perfectly!

Comment: loadtxt does not load also the column names which happen with names=True on genfromtxt

Comment: Can I ask - is `open` local to that single line? As in, does the file close at the end of the line?

Comment: Yes, it closes the file. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011797/open-read-and-close-a-file-in-1-line-of-code

Comment: I would suggest using the seocnd method since `loadtxt` is awfully slow. Alternatively `pandas` is pretty great for the purpose

Comment: @fireball.1 speed tests for claims like this would be great for posterity

Answer (score 6):

I think using `dtype` where there is a name row is confusing the routine.  Try

```
>>> r = np.genfromtxt(fname, delimiter=',', names=True)
>>> r
array([[  6.11882430e+02,   9.08956010e+03,   5.13300000e+03,
          8.64075140e+02,   1.71537476e+03,   7.65227770e+02,
          1.29111196e+12],
       [  6.11882430e+02,   9.08956010e+03,   5.13300000e+03,
          8.64075140e+02,   1.71537476e+03,   7.65227770e+02,
          1.29111311e+12],
       [  6.11882430e+02,   9.08956010e+03,   5.13300000e+03,
          8.64075140e+02,   1.71537476e+03,   7.65227770e+02,
          1.29112065e+12]])
>>> r[:,0]    # Slice 0'th column
array([ 611.88243,  611.88243,  611.88243])
```

Comment: Interestingly, this does not change the result in my case.  I am using Python 2.5 and numpy 1.4.1 so maybe that is the problem

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6 and NumPy 1.3.0!  I like the older behavior better.

Answer (score 4):

You can read a CSV file with headers into a [NumPy structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) with [np.genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html). For example:

```
import numpy as np

csv_fname = 'file.csv'
with open(csv_fname, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("""\
"A","B","C","D","E","F","timestamp"
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291111964948E12
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291113113366E12
611.88243,9089.5601,5133.0,864.07514,1715.37476,765.22777,1.291120650486E12
""")

# Read the CSV file into a Numpy record array
r = np.genfromtxt(csv_fname, delimiter=',', names=True, case_sensitive=True)
print(repr(r))
```

which looks like this:

```
array([(611.88243, 9089.5601, 5133., 864.07514, 1715.37476, 765.22777, 1.29111196e+12),
       (611.88243, 9089.5601, 5133., 864.07514, 1715.37476, 765.22777, 1.29111311e+12),
       (611.88243, 9089.5601, 5133., 864.07514, 1715.37476, 765.22777, 1.29112065e+12)],
      dtype=[('A', '<f8'), ('B', '<f8'), ('C', '<f8'), ('D', '<f8'), ('E', '<f8'), ('F', '<f8'), ('timestamp', '<f8')])
```

You can access a named column like this `r['E']`:

```
array([1715.37476, 1715.37476, 1715.37476])
```

---

Note: this answer previously used [np.recfromcsv](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) to read the data into a [NumPy record array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html). While there was nothing wrong with that method, structured arrays are generally better than record arrays for speed and compatibility.