# open read and close a file in 1 line of code

Tags: python, readfile

Now I use:

```
pageHeadSectionFile = open('pagehead.section.htm','r')
output = pageHeadSectionFile.read()
pageHeadSectionFile.close()
```

But to make the code look better, I can do:

```
output = open('pagehead.section.htm','r').read()
```

When using the above syntax, how do I close the file to free up system resources?

Comment: There is nothing inherently more attractive about one-liners. Code is read far more often than it is written, and should be written for comprehension, not for "coolness." The only exception is when there is a well-known idiom in a language, but I am unaware of one in this case.

Comment: @drdwilcox: Cryptic one-liners are bad, declarative one-liners are good. There is no reason (at least I cannot see one), why there is no function wrapper in the core to read a file (such common need) in a single function call. Something like `contents = os.readfile(path)`. If I wanted to do something fancier, then ok, I'd happily use `with open(path) as fd: contents = fd.read()`. Of course one can write its own wrapper, but that's what the core is for, to provide the useful to abstractions to programmers.

Comment: It's true that code is read far more than it's written, but the implication that longer code is just as good as short code couldn't be more wrong. If you invest time in making your code as short as possible (without resorting to clever tricks that are hard to understand), that investment will pay off over and over when the code is read. Every line you write is a disservice to anyone reading your code, so you should strive to write as little as possible. Remember the famous quote from Pascal: "I made this letter longer only because I have not had the leisure to make it shorter."

Comment: One may be in an environment where they need to write one-liners, like when debugging in pdb. Don't belittle other people's questions.

Comment: Vertical space is valuable. If I can read a whole funcion in one screen I am happy. Lots of empty space doesn't make your code more readable, it is just a habbit.

Comment: why not use... a function? 0.0

Answer (score 254, accepted):

You don't really have to close it - Python will do it automatically either during garbage collection or at program exit. But as @delnan noted, it's better practice to explicitly close it for various reasons.

So, what you can do to keep it short, simple and explicit:

```
with open('pagehead.section.htm', 'r') as f:
    output = f.read()
```

Now it's just two lines and pretty readable, I think.

Comment: I am using it on GAE, so the question is if it will cost me extra resources since I am not closing the file "correctly"

Comment: @1qazxsw2 If you use the [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) the file resource will be closed properly for you.

Comment: @1qazxsw2, the `with` statement makes sure the file is closed "correctly", it's even better than an explicit `close`. And it should be available in GAE's Python 2.5. See http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm

Comment: Re first sentence: Python will close it *eventually*. But that doesn't mean you should forget about closing. Even with refcounting, the file may stay open far longer than you think and want (e.g. if it happens to be referred to by cycles). This goes thrice in Python implementations that have a decent GC, where you have no guarantee that anything is GC'd at any particular time. Even the [CPython documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) says you shouldn't rely on GC for cleanup like this. The latter part of the answer should be bold.

Comment: If you really need a *one-liner*, it is possible to put the `output = f.read()` part on the same line after the `:`.

Comment: Tim thanks for noting the difference between ".close()" and ".close". I could not understand why the file was not being closed! After I added the () it closed :-)

Comment: I started out using a oneliner to assert on the equality of two xml files in py.test. As I used a temporary folder for the test, that was supposed to be recreated every time, I ran in to trouble since Python doesn't close the file immediately. I got an EBUSY error because the folder could not be deleted. Changing to this method and doing the comparison over several rows of code solved that issue.

Comment: "open read and close a file in 1 line of code" this is two lines, and does not answer the question.

Comment: If I do `content = open(f).read()`, is the file object being kept somewhere in memory, but inaccessible ? or is the file closed automatically after read()?

Comment: That’s implementation dependent - see Sven’s answer.

Comment: Answer is obsolete. Correct answer using modern python is `Path('pagehead.section.htm').read_text()`

Comment: You have to import Path from pathlib, this is not one line.

Comment: @aaronsteers keep in mind that this method is not suitable for large files. For large files better it is better to use generators.

Comment: @RobBird - Respectfully, the import doesn't count imho - this is a one-liner and the library is a standard lib. Rationale: (1) code readability as a priority is inferred from OP question "open read and close a file in 1 line of code", (2) in terms of readability, it is only one line, (3) your response implies that pathlib isn't already imported, which we can't assume.

Comment: @igoras1993 - I agree with yo. According to OP's question "open read and close a file in 1 line of code", inference is that the entire file will be read and stored in memory in a single var. If the file is large, this question is moot.

Answer (score 186):

Python Standard Library [Pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module does what you looking for:

```
Path('pagehead.section.htm').read_text()
```

Don't forget to import Path:

```
jsk@dev1:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Sep 10 2016, 08:21:44)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> (Path("/etc") / "hostname").read_text()
'dev1.example\n'
```

On Python 27 install backported [`pathlib`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib) or [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2)

Comment: The other answers proposing `with` are fine, but `with` is a statement, not an expression. This `pathlib` answer is the only reply to the original question that can be embedded in a Python expression. Something like `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or pathlib.Path('SECRET_KEY').read_bytes()`

Comment: Nice addition of `pathlib`! [« The file is opened then closed. »](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text)

Answer (score 27):

Using CPython, your file will be closed immediately after the line is executed, because the file object is immediately garbage collected.  There are two drawbacks, though:

1. In Python implementations different from CPython, the file often isn't immediately closed, but rather at a later time, beyond your control.
2. In Python 3.2 or above, this will throw a `ResourceWarning`, if enabled.

Better to invest one additional line:

```
with open('pagehead.section.htm','r') as f:
    output = f.read()
```

This will ensure that the file is correctly closed under all circumstances.

Answer (score 23):

No need to import any special libraries to do this.

**Use normal syntax and it will open the file for reading then close it.**

```
with open("/etc/hostname","r") as f: print f.read()
```

**or**

```
with open("/etc/hosts","r") as f: x = f.read().splitlines()
```

**which gives you an array x containing the lines, and can be printed like so:**

```
for line in x: print line
```

---

### These one-liners are very helpful for maintenance - basically self-documenting.

Answer (score 12):

What you can do is to use the `with` statement, and write the two steps on one line:

```
>>> with open('pagehead.section.htm', 'r') as fin: output = fin.read();
>>> print(output)
some content
```

The `with` statement will take care to call `__exit__` function of the given object even if something bad happened in your code; it's close to the `try... finally` syntax. For  object returned by `open`, `__exit__` corresponds to file closure.

This statement has been introduced with Python 2.6.

Comment: Small clarification: according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) `with` was introduced in Python 2.5, but had to be [explicitly imported](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-343-the-with-statement) from `__future__`. It became available from all contexts in Python 2.6.

Answer (score 6):

I think the most natural way for achieving this is to define a function.

```
def read(filename):
    f = open(filename, 'r')
    output = f.read()
    f.close()
    return output
```

Then you can do the following:

```
output = read('pagehead.section.htm')
```

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. Just `return open(filename, 'r').read()` does the same thing, because your `f.close` is not guaranteed to be called and the `close` will be called by garbage collection anyway when the function exits.

Answer (score 5):

use [ilio](https://github.com/gowhari/ilio): (inline io):

just one function call instead of file open(), read(), close().

```
from ilio import read

content = read('filename')
```

Answer (score 1):

I frequently do something like this when I need to get a few lines surrounding something I've grepped in a log file:

```
$ grep -n "xlrd" requirements.txt | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
54

$ python -c "with open('requirements.txt') as file: print ''.join(file.readlines()[52:55])"
wsgiref==0.1.2
xlrd==0.9.2
xlwt==0.7.5
```

Comment: Completely unrelated to the original topic, but you should look into `grep -A <n>`, `grep -B <n>`, and `grep -C <n>`, if it is helpful. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9083/1830159

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('pagehead.section.htm')as f:contents=f.read()
```

Comment: How is this any different from the top 3 answers?

Comment: The biggest difference is that it is only one line as the question specified. Personally I can't find any beyond that but feel free to critique my work rather than actually contributing to the question yourself.

Comment: The shortest, built-in way to achieve opening, reading, and closing a file in Python is using 2 logical lines whether it's condensed down to 1 line or not. So I don't see this answer to be effectively any different from the 3 original answers.

Comment: It does not matter if its 'effectively' different. I got to this page looking for one-line syntax that might be used with `python -c` on the command line, so posting 2-line answers does not help.

Comment: @user5359531 I don't see your point: do you know that you can quote python expressions with `"`, use `;` to append two instructions, and delete newline after `:` ? Following expression works just fine for me : `$> python -c "with open('some file', 'r') as f: print(next(f))"`

Answer (score 0):

Using [`more_itertools.with_iter`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.with_iter), it is possible to open, read, close and assign an equivalent `output` in one line (excluding the import statement):

```
import more_itertools as mit


output = "".join(line for line in mit.with_iter(open("pagehead.section.htm", "r")))
```

Although possible, I would look for another approach other than assigning the contents of a file to a variable, i.e. lazy iteration - this can be done using a traditional `with` block or in the example above by removing `join()` and iterating `output`.

Comment: You can import inside the oneliner as well. `"".join(line for line in __import__('more_itertools').with_iter(open("pagehead.section.htm", "r")))` This works just fine, and eliminates the need for a line for the import.

Comment: I completely agree with you. However while discussing solving tasks with oneliners, I've often found myself in arguments where the agreed outcome should be a single line of code pasted into a fresh python shell. Such challenges rarely conform to pep8. It's in no way a good practice for writing code, it was only meant as a tip to remove the need for imports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that warm and fuzzy feeling just go with *with*.

For python 3.6 I ran these two programs under a fresh start of IDLE, giving runtimes of:

```
0.002000093460083008  Test A
0.0020003318786621094 Test B: with guaranteed close
```

So not much of a difference.

```
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
# Desc: Test A for reading a text file line-by-line into a list
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*

import sys
import time

#                                  # MAINLINE
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("OK, starting program...")

    inTextFile = '/Users/Mike/Desktop/garbage.txt'

#                                  # Test: A: no 'with;
    c=[]
    start_time = time.time()
    c = open(inTextFile).read().splitlines()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    print("OK, program execution has ended.")
    sys.exit()                     # END MAINLINE
```

OUTPUT:

```
OK, starting program...
--- 0.002000093460083008 seconds ---
OK, program execution has ended.

#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*
# Desc: Test B for reading a text file line-by-line into a list
#--------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*---------*

import sys
import time

#                                  # MAINLINE
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("OK, starting program...")

    inTextFile = '/Users/Mike/Desktop/garbage.txt'

#                                  # Test: B: using 'with'
    c=[]
    start_time = time.time()
    with open(inTextFile) as D: c = D.read().splitlines()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))

    print("OK, program execution has ended.")
    sys.exit()                     # END MAINLINE
```

OUTPUT:

```
OK, starting program...
--- 0.0020003318786621094 seconds ---
OK, program execution has ended.
```