# Convert downloaded image into file object in single line

Tags: python, python-2.7, file

This is quote from an DeathByCaptcha API documentation I am using.

```
dict deathbycaptcha.Client.decode(file imageFile, int timeout)
dict deathbycaptcha.Client.decode(str imageFileName, int timeout)
```

It can either accept path to image file or the file object

I have this line of code.

```
client.decode(urllib.urlopen('https://example/image.jpg').read(), 30)
```

But its giving me error because `.read()` does returns `file-like` object.

My preference is to do it in one line.

Is there any way I can easily cast that stream read by `read()` to file-like object?

If not possible in one line like we do in PHP `(string) 100` then I will accept a multi-line

Comment: Do you want it to be a single line so that your code is succinct to read? If so, you could just create a function that reads from a URL and returns a file object.

Comment: @AlexW Umm if not possible in one line like we do in PHP `(string) 100` then I will accept a multi-line solution.

Comment: [Python - open read and close a file in 1 line of code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011797/open-read-and-close-a-file-in-1-line-of-code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about `urllib.urlopen`, but you can use [urllib2.urlopen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) method to get `file-like` object you can pass to `decode` function. It will look more or less like:

```
client.decode(urllib2.urlopen('https://example/image.jpg'), 30)
```

EDIT: I took a look at [urllib documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) and it looks like `urllib.urlopen` also returns `file-like` object.

Comment: @Unimar cool :), just keep in mind that error handling is missing in this one-liner so it will just throw exception in case of any issues (with connection e.g.).

Comment: Yeah i can understand ... I wanted "one-liner" solution and you provided it . thanks