# How do I convert lines of text into HTML links using python?

Tags: python

The code saves a list of URLs. I want to take the lines of text and covert them to links within an HTML file by adding the A tags and place those links within properly formatted HTML code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import shutil

try: 
    from googlesearch import search 
except ImportError:  
    print("No module named 'google' found") 

#keyword query user input
query = raw_input('Enter keyword or keywords to search: ')

#print results from search into a file called keyword.txt
with open("keyword.txt","w+") as f:
     for j in search(query, tld='co.in', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=200, pause=3):
      f.write("%s\n" % j)
f.close() 

#add keyword to list of keywords file
sys.stdout=open("keywords","a+") 
print (query) 
sys.stdout.close()

#rename file to reflect query input
os.rename('keyword.txt',query + ".txt") 

#move created data file to proper directory and cleanup mess
source = os.listdir("/home/user/search/")
destination = "/home/user/search/index/"
for files in source:
    if files.endswith(".txt"):
    shutil.copy(files,destination)
os.remove(query + ".txt")
```

Expected results would be an HTML file with clickable links

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to print the required HTML tags along with what you are printing right now?

Comment: When I try:  f.write('atag' "%s\n" % j ("%s\n" % j, 'btag'))  I get this error: TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it appears that you are struggling to write the url string obtained from the `search` function into a file along with the required HTML tags. Try:

```
with open("keyword.txt","w+") as f:
    for j in search(query, tld='co.in', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=200, pause=3):
        f.write('<a href="{0}">{1}</a> <br>\n'.format(j,j))
```

Which will write each url and add hyperlinks to the url. You might want to print `<html> ... </html>` and  `<body> ... </body>` tags as well to `keyword.txt`. This can be done like

```
with open("keyword.txt","w+") as f:
   f.write('<html> \n <body> \n')
   for j in search(query, tld='co.in', lang='en', num=10, start=0, stop=200, pause=3):
      f.write('<a href="{0}">{1}</a> <br>\n'.format(j,j))
   f.write('\n</body> \n </html>')
```

And, you don't have to close the file using `f.close()` if you use `with open` see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8011836/937153

Personally, I prefer `format` over `%`. I will be careful about presenting a comparison between the two here. You can see [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/937153) for a detailed discussion on this topic.

Comment: I have altered the code since then, however you have certainly helped me solve this problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: Glad I could help :)