# Is `txt = open('file.txt').read()` worse than `with open('file.txt') as fh: txt = fh.read()`?

Tags: python

In other words, when would Python close the file in first example? Would it be done immediately after reading from a file and realizing than there's no references to the file handler returned by `open('file.txt')`? If that's the case, it seems that `with` statement is not necessary here. Are there any caveats?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011797/open-read-and-close-a-file-in-1-line-of-code/8011836

Comment: Well, I hoped to find out what exactly happens in both cases. But that answer is the best approach to that. Thanks!