# Can I read a text file in Python in one function call?

Tags: python

Each time I start a new Python project, I define a `read_file` method. Something like:

```
def read_file(file_name: str) -> List[str]:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return lines
```

Usually, I also add a `write_file` method.

Is there a Python package from which I can import a method with the same interface? If there isn't such a package I will create one :)

I want to emphasize that I'm aware of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011797/open-read-and-close-a-file-in-1-line-of-code) solutions, but I want this exact interface because it is simpler.

Comment: `pathlib`'s `.read_text()` is the closest built-in thing I can think of, but that returns a string rather than a list of lines.

Comment: thanks @jaonharper. In addition to the difference in the output, pathlib's solution also requires constructing a `Path` object, which I find redundant for my use case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense to make a function for this. It would be more readable and faster to write `open(file_name).readlines()` instead of `read_file(file_name)`.
Don't worry about this solution not containing a `with`, `read_lines` is just as unsafe as `open` is