# Splitting a line with different separators in python

Tags: python, split

I have a text file containing some data stored in three columns. The first column is separated from the second by a comma (,) and a tab (\t) and the same for the separation between the second and the third. However, the last column is terminated with a comma and a newline command (\n). Here is an example:

```
0.782470450031, 0.0,    0.0,
0.775811285325, 0.025,  0.0,
0.768594334758, 0.05,   0.0,
0.761101295788, 0.075,  0.0,
```

I would like to read this file and transform it into an array. If the columns were only separated by a comma I would just do:

```
f=open(filename,'r')
data=[map(float,line.split(',')) for line in f]
data=np.array(data)
```

But I am not exactly sure how to do this in this case.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315506/load-csv-into-2d-matrix-with-numpy-for-plotting

Comment: Use the `csv` module.

Comment: Don't even worry about the extra white space, tabs, etc. The `float` conversion will discard all of that for example `float('\t12.5\t\n')` will produce the float `12.5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regex:

```
re.split(r',\t', line)
```

If this is CSV file, you don't need regex, there are many tools that does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

I did use `re` module.

```
data=[map(float,re.split(r',\t*', line)) for line in f]
data=np.array(data)
```